# Android Application Background data

Tags: android

I got all the running background process

but i want a list of running/installed application which requires internet

for example

Take Facebook application when i installed in phone it will in background and requires internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS flag, like:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = 
    p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | 
                                      PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS)
```

Comment: can i specifically get the list of installed application which have this permission "android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: @Bucks, nope don't think so. Should be a simple case of list filtering though, no? Can't expect the API to provide everything anyone might ever want ;)